# javascript send object's attributes to function

Tags: javascript, object

i have a situation i have been thinking for a while and cant seem to find logic to solve it. hope you can.

i have a series of buttons that i would like to track, an example of one is this:

when a button is clicked a function is called, sending some strings and an object with a series of attributes. different buttons have different sets of attributes.

```
$(".btn").on('click', function(ev){
   trackFunction("Purchase","apply_promo", { product_code: "product1", last_page: "home", refer: "facebook", promo: "12345" });
});
```

The track function will then receive this and send it to my analytics software
but i need it to be sent in this format

```
dataToSend = { event_type : eventType, event_value: eventValue, data };
```

where data is each and every attribute from the object the button is sending. 
in that example it woud be something like this

```
dataToSend = { event_type : eventType, event_value: eventValue, data.product_code, data.last_page, data.refer, data.promo };`
```

here is my tracking function :

```
function trackFunction(eventType, eventValue, data ) {
   dataToSend = { event_type : eventType, event_value: eventValue, data };
   analyze(dataToSend);
   return true;
}
```

the problem here is that not every button is sending the same attributes inside the object so i cant hardcode the output.

hope i made myself clear.
and thank you so much.

Comment: Where is your problem exactly ? At the construction, you don't know how to get all the attributes of an object ? Or at the end, you don't know to which property you must access ?

Comment: i dont know how to get all the attributes of the object and then send them all together to a function.

Comment: Does the attributes are only text values ?

Comment: yes all strings, some buttons contain lets say, promo number and price, while others contain just price, and barcode. not all the buttons contain the same attributes.

Comment: So why don't you send directly the object ?

Comment: In `dataToSend = { event_type : eventType, event_value: eventValue, data };` which should be the type of `data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you add the common properties to the object each time. The downside is that you're altering a function parameter which is generally a bad idea because it might cause weird bugs:

```
function track(a, b, data) {
    data.a = a;
    data.b = b;
    sendData(data);
}
```

Or you turn it around by iterating over the object's properties:

```
function track(a, b, data) {
    var send = {a: a, b: b}, k;
    for (k in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            send[k] = data[k];
        }
    } 
    sendData(send);
}
```

If you use lodash, underscore, or jQuery (or probably every other JS framework out there) you usually have an `extend` function at your disposal, which does pretty much what you want (and internally the same as the second example).

```
// with underscore:
function track(a, b, data) {
    sendData(_.extend({a: a, b: b}, data));
}
```